# How to submit data in Adaptive card Execute action from Outlook to web api without using azure bot service?

Tags: azure, outlook, azure-web-app-service, azure-bot-service, adaptive-cards

I have an API which is hosted on Azure WebApp service, and it's sending adaptive card v1.0 email to user's outlook client, then user click action.Http button to response the card.  Now I want to use new v1.4 card, but in v1.4 the action.Http button does not show up in Outlook, the only working button is action.Execute. However, there is no url attribute in action.Execute to let me specify where the data should be sent to, and I don't want to buy additional bot service.  Is there any way for this?  Thank you.

Comment: Check out the documentation which gives clear flow of connecting outlook to web API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/adaptive-card

Comment: @qwer11121 did you manage to solve your problem? I'm currently facing the same problem and don't want tp pay extra to use an Azure Bot just to process an adaptive card response.